# Xbee S2 Reading API frame

Tags: xbee

while i read API frames in ardiuno

in Serial window i got simply

> FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF

```
 void setup() 
    { 
      Serial.begin(9600); 
    } 
    void loop() 
    { 
      if (Serial.available()>=0){ 
        for(int i=0;i<22;i++)
        { 
          Serial.print(Serial.read(),HEX); 
          Serial.print(","); 
        } 
       Serial.println(); 
      } 

    }
```

Plz someone give me a solution. i could not identify the problem

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to read when `Serial.available()` indicates there isn't anything there to read, so `Serial.read()` is probably returning -1.

```
void setup() 
{ 
  Serial.begin(9600); 
} 
void loop() 
{ 
  if (Serial.available()>0){ 
      Serial.println(Serial.read(),HEX); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply i connected Tx and Rx of Xbee to Rx and Tx of ardiuno  i just simply try to read API frames but i didnt get anything

Answer (score -1):

change the line serial.available()>=0 to serial.available()>22
u will get data.

Comment: This makes no sense. If `serial.available()` is greater than 22, then it'll also be greater than or equal to 0.